# How to find a range in a single a column differentiating the strings

Tags: excel, vba

I am facing an issue where to find the specific range in a column while building a macro using VBA script. here is the column data to sort it out using VBA

[image]

in the above table we have 2 columns measure and name. under the B column i have multiple strings which starts with A101 or A102 or some other dynamic string name. But,here i have to run the macro to capture the data from starting Alphabet to ending of the same alphabet. example : under the column B the row b2 starts with A and same Alphabet ended at B14 and this ranges are dynamic and the Alphabets or characters are also dynamic so kindly help me with the code.

Comment: What's the problem?

Comment: Please modify your question to make your example match your text. For example, D103 never logged in but logged out 3 times. So, which range do you want? Is it all instances of D103? Or all instances of "D???" And for either case, are there case where a range specified isn't contiguous?

Comment: First of all thanks Maciej los for reply immediate .
In the above example i just given a sample format of the table. Actually in our results sheet have multiple instances with user defined names. but i have to capture them for each and individual complete instance. i mean from starting instance A to ending 
 instance A & similary for D also but the number of rows will not be static

Comment: Thanks Variatus for replying me . In the above example i just given a sample format of the table. Actually in our results sheet have multiple instances with user defined names. but i have to capture them for each and individual complete instance. i mean from starting instance A to ending instance A & similary for D also but the number of rows will not be static